# Django wont save form data to postgres database

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a from that won't save any data with form.save() method. It worked before I migrated my whole db to postgres. I think the problem might be in my models file. I'm really new to postgres.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      weight = ArrayField(
      models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True),
      null=True,
    
)
height = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
date = ArrayField(
    models.DateField(auto_now_add=True),
    null=True,
    
)
def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
       Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from users import models
from users.models import Profile
from django.core import serializers
from .forms import WeightForm
import logging
import json


def home(request):
    form = WeightForm()
    if request.is_ajax():
       profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, id = request.user.id)
       form = WeightForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          return JsonResponse({
            'msg': 'Success'
        })
       
    
return render(request, 'Landing/index.html',{'form':form})
```

## Update

forms.py: I haven't changed anything in this file before the migration

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from users.models import Profile
from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Submit, Row, Column

class WeightForm(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
          model = Profile
          fields = ['weight','height']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(WeightForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for visible in self.visible_fields():
        visible.field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'input'

    self.fields['weight'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Your Weight'
    self.fields['height'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Your Height'
```

AJAX: This works, when I submit the form I get the success message

```
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log("Ready!");

const form = document.getElementById("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", submitHandler);

function submitHandler(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{% url "landing-home" %}',
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        
        success: function(data){
            if(data.msg == 'Success'){
                alert("Form is submitted!");
            }
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: Can you paste `WeightForm`? And how do you use this endpoint?

Comment: do you get the success response from endpoint?

Comment: Yes i do. In the browsers alert window

Comment: Any ideas about my problem?

Comment: Have you checked that you receive the data? if you haven't checked, so print(request.POST), then let us know.

Comment: Hello, heres what I get from pringint request.POST <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['uCjeVsQveJEi0fjRldkBd19Tf38odUgJiV7iA8jgFE5uGQISAD46DBHOSLNw5q66'], 'weight': ['65'], 'height': ['45']}> So basically, I get the data.

Comment: The strange thing is that when I used the SQL lite database everything worked just fine. I switched so I can use ArrayFields